# How can I use callback in python?

Tags: python-2.7, parallel-processing, callback

I have a code which get scores of a match every time and also at the same time it read bets. At some circumstances it needs to know whats the score now which needs to be updated regularly else we miss the state of game but to have controller at rates is must.

I want a to know, is there a package which can parallely update the score in a variable of current thread and whenever I need to access this variable then I can.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable which you will access via both threads.